# Excel alternative that uses JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a very simple Excel alternative that is cross platform, open source and uses JavaScript instead of the terrible Excel language (whatever it is called). So that every cell can have a script with a readable syntax, indentation etc.
It would also be nice to have html support and a way to use javascript/css libraries to render graphics, charts etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to try an Add-in, there is a way to use Javascript, HTML and css in Excel. It's called Funfun and it hosts an online editor with an embedded spreadsheet so the transition isn't hard between the website to Excel.

Here is a chart I made with Highcharts:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a61c190404f66229bda3f0f

In this example I took the chart from a [Highchart demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble), and replaced the data with mine. I store my data in the embedded spreadsheet, and thanks to a json file I can use it in my javascript code.

That is how I get my data from the spreadsheet with the json file:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:E16"
}
```

I store it in my script.js with the right format so I can directly load it in Highcharts (for numbers you must convert your data into floats or int):

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 1; i < $internal.data.length; i++)
  data.push(
    {
      x: parseFloat($internal.data[i][2]),
      y: parseFloat($internal.data[i][3]),
      z: parseFloat($internal.data[i][4]),
      name: $internal.data[i][1],
      country: $internal.data[i][0]
    }
  );
```

After You've chosen all of you're options for your chart you can add your data:

```
series: [{
        data: data
    }]
```

Once you are happy with your chart you can directly load it into Excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: final]

Of course you can use another library than Highcharts, there are a lot of powerful libraries for data visualization like charts.js and D3.js.

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**